# Error when trying to add a row to a dataframe

Tags: r

I am pretty noob in R and this is driving me crazy. When I try to add a new row to this data frame it gives me this strange error and instead of adding a new name it adds . Does anyone know how to solve this? I really need help

```
MENU <- function()
{
  P1=readline(prompt="Insert Name1:")

  P2=readline(prompt="Inset Name2:")
  TA=data.frame(names=c(P1,P2),games=c(0,0),points=c(100,100),stringsAsFactors= F)

  write.table(TA,"C://Users//aleja//Documents//names.txt")

  TA=read.table("C://Users//aleja//Documents//names.txt")

  P1=readline(prompt="Insert Name1:")

  new=list(names=P1,games=0,points=100)

  TA=rbind(TA,new)
}
```

So this is what happens:

```
Insert Name1:ale

Inset Name2:ana

Insert Name1:jose

**Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "jose") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated**
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thank u very much! Could you explain me why it didn't work with the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep everything in your function the same, it would be fixed by:

```
MENU<-fucntion()

{

P1=readline(prompt="Insert Name1:")

P2=readline(prompt="Inset Name2:")

TA=data.frame(names=c(P1,P2),games=c(0,0),points=c(100,100),stringsAsFactors= F)

write.table(TA,"C://Users//aleja//Documents//names.txt")

TA=read.table("C://Users//aleja//Documents//names.txt")

P1=readline(prompt="Insert Name1:")

new=data.frame(names=P1,games=0,points=100)

TA=rbind(TA,new)

}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: The only thing is that this converts `names` to factors.  If OP wants to keep `names` as strings, then you should add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to `read.table` (which, incidentally, would remove the error from OP's code).